# SQL Server Determine Most Occurances Of Data In A Group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, grouping

Let's say I have the following:

```
COL1      COL2     COL3  

ABC       DATA1      
ABC       DATA1      
ABC       DATA2  
ABC       DATA3  
DEF       INFO1  
DEF       INFO2  
DEF       INFO3  
DEF       INFO3
```

I want to use SQL to propagate the value that occurs most often in a group into COL3 for that group.  So, my results would be:

```
COL1      COL2     COL3  

ABC       DATA1    DATA1     
ABC       DATA1    DATA1  
ABC       DATA2    DATA1  
ABC       DATA3    DATA1  
DEF       INFO1    INFO3  
DEF       INFO2    INFO3  
DEF       INFO3    INFO3  
DEF       INFO3    INFO3
```

Any ideas?  SQL Server 2012.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? We help fix code, we're not here to solve your problems for you.

Comment: how are ties resolved?

Comment: Sorry, Marc - I just had no idea where to start

Comment: Beth, Ties are fine - either selection would work equally as well

Answer (score 0):

```
;With cte
as
(
col1,col2,row_number() over (partition by col1,col2 order by col1)  as rownum
)
select col1,col2,b.col2 as col3
from yourtable  t
cross apply
( select top1  col2 from cte c where c.col1=t.col1 order by rownum desc) b
```

Comment: Thank you!  This was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I would write it that way:

```
UPDATE P SET P.Col3=T.Col2
FROM Propagation P
JOIN(
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES Col1, Col2
    FROM Propagation
    GROUP BY Col1, Col2
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    ) T ON T.Col1=P.Col1
```

Comment: Thanks! The answer I developed was a combination of both these answers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all!  I used a combination of the answers to get it to work. Here is what I came up with:

```
WITH OCCUR_EXT
  as
    (
     SELECT [COL1], [COL2], row_number() over (partition by [COL1], [COL2] order by [COL1]) as TOT_OCCUR
       FROM [T_TABLEDATA]
      WHERE [COL2] > ''
    ),

 DOM_ASSGN
  as
    (
     SELECT *
         FROM 
         (SELECT *, 
                row_number() 
           OVER
               (partition by [COL1] order by [COL1], TOT_OCCUR DESC) as ROW_NMBR
                     FROM OCCUR_EXT ) source
                    WHERE ROW_NMBR = 1
    )

UPDATE [T_TABLEDATA]
   SET [T_TABLEDATA].[COL3] = [DOM_ASSGN].[COL2]
  FROM [T_TABLEDATA], [DOM_ASSGN]
  WHERE [T_TABLEDATA].[COL1] = [DOM_ASSGN].[COL1]
  GO
```